# How to make the tool bar same as status bar

Tags: ios, ios7

So I've already developed an app the I released for `iOS 6` quite a long time ago. Well I want to update it for `iOS 7`. With the `iOS 7` theme you could call it makes the toolbar I have on my app look horrible. What I want to do is create a toolbar someway like how vine and twitters are, ill include screen shots of how mine looks compared to those. I see in xcode that I can enable this by selecting the view controller then enabling the top bar but its an navigation bar not a tool bar. Is this possible? Anyways here is a link to the screen shot I took,

[image]

Comment: you want to make the status bar separate from the app right?

Comment: best way that i had used is to make navigation bar image to 640*64 size this would automatically set to as the io7

Comment: I havent tried any coding yet, as its been quite a while since ive been in iOS development and dont really remember much. Im not sure if i want the status bar separate from the app but im guessing yes. What i want to do it have it so it looks smooth and one solid color, like vine and twitters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that(iOS 7) you want to set the **NavigationBar** Image like:

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

for more details check this also:

[Customize-Navigation-status-bar-ios-7](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

[iOS 7 Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html)

**EDIT:**

if you want to set color in **toolbar** try this:

```
 Yourtoolbar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];//set here whatever you want.
```

May you want the height of toolbar 64pts not 44pts,for that you need to set the bar's *barPosition* property to **UIBarPositionTopAttached**.

May it will help you.

Comment: Problem is im not using a navigation bar im using a tool bar so i can add buttons to it.

Comment: @user3180303 can you explain brief what you want exactly?what you try ?

Comment: Ok ill try my best. So as you can see in the list of images the very last image is my application, the top bar below the status bar is a tool bar not a navigation bar, so i can add buttons and text to the bar. Also in the last image you can see that there is a separator from the outline of the status bar so it doesn't look so great with that. Now say i wanted to make the tool bar and the status bar blue with no line separators, and make it look all in one. Like the other ones.

Comment: Did you try changing the tint color of tool bar and status bar to same color?

Comment: @user3180303 check my edit answer may it will help you.